# Getting Attribute From HTML Using .getAttribute() Failed

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

**HTML**

```
<select disabled class="kurir full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" name="kurir" data-productid="316">
    ...
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".kurir").change(function() {
    var productid = $(this).getAttribute('data-productid');
    alert (productid);
});
```

Why I can't get `316` from `data-productid`? What did I missed here?

Thank you.

Comment: use `.attr('data-productid');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get attribute value like following.

```
this.getAttribute('data-productid')
```

Or

```
$(this).attr('data-productid')
```

Comment: Or `$(this).data('productid')`

Comment: Obviously. @KartikeyaKhosla

Answer (score 3):

.getAttribute is the javascript  method we can't use it is jquery object method.

so you can use it below syntax- this.getAttribute('data-productid');

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var productid = $(this).data('productid');
```